# How to check if a directory is a git repository in C#

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I've started using LibGit2Sharp in my project and I have to admit its pretty awesome. I'm glad i didnt go the command line route with processinfo. But I have a question which I couldn't find an answer for in the  wiki and could not find a test in the source code that had it. How can you check with LibGit2Sharp if a folder is a git repository?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call `Repository.IsValid(path)`. The source code for `Repository` is [here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp/Repository.cs).

The path can be either to the `.git` folder or to the working directory.